# Проблема с выводом постов из таксономии через get_posts()

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте. Есть вопрос, на который не могу найти решение. Весь код привел для понимания вывода. Проблема только в обозначении параметров в самом начале. Осложняется тем что функция работает при выключенном плагине polylang, который в свою очередь я устанавливал после q-translate, который оставляет после удаления множество хвостов, как например битые поля в ACF, но не выводит этот код при включенной мультиязычности. Не знаю как это связано.
Я пытаюсь продебажить здесь проблему и нашел, что 'post_type' => 'solutions' не распознается, хотя по скриншоту такой тип поста существует - http://take.ms/wRhIN. Здесь видно, что есть такой post_type у таксономии, а в админке внутри есть 6 категорий, в каждой по определенному количеству постов. Почему так происходит? или как дебажить такие места, подскажите, пожалуйста? (Может, как вывод отдельных постов или категорий через функции или те же var_dump.)

```
<?php
        $posts_a = array();
        $terms = get_terms("solutions_cat");
        if (count($terms)) {
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $args = array(
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                    'post_type' => 'solutions',
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'solutions_cat' => $term->slug
                );
                var_dump($term);
                $posts = get_posts($args);
                if ($posts) {
                    foreach ($posts as $post) {
                        $posts_a[$term->name][] = $post;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if ($posts_a):
            ?>
            <div class="solutions__prod-wrap">
                <? $c_cat = '';
                foreach ($posts_a as $cat => $posts):
                    ?>
                    <div class="solutions__prod">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <h2 class="solutions__title"><?= $cat ?></h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="solutions__prod-list">

                                        <div class="solutions__prod-slider" uk-slider="center: false">

                                            <div class="uk-position-relative">

                                                <div class="uk-slider-container uk-light">
                                                    <ul class="uk-slider-items uk-child-width-1-1 uk-child-width-1-2@s uk-child-width-1-4@l  uk-grid-small">
                                                        <? foreach ($posts as $post): setup_postdata($post); ?>
                                                            <li class="solutions__prod-list_order-item">
                                                                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="solutions__prod-list-item tag-tag-<?php $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'solutions_tags', array("fields" => "ids")); echo implode(' tag-tag-', $term_list);  ?>">
                                                                    <div class="solutions_product-item_image-section">
                                                                        <?php
                                                                        MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail('solutions', 'solutions-mini', NULL,  'solutions-solutions-mini-thumbnail');
                                                                        ?>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <h3 class="solutions_product-item_title"><?php the_title();?></h3>
                                                                    <div class="solutions_product-item_description">
                                                                        <?php the_excerpt();?>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="solutions_product-item_link-section">
                                                                        <div class="solutions_product-item_link">Learn more ></div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </a>
                                                            </li>
                                                        <? endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();?>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="uk-hidden@s uk-light">
                                                    <a class="uk-position-center-left uk-position-small" href="#" uk-slidenav-previous uk-slider-item="previous"></a>
                                                    <a class="uk-position-center-right uk-position-small" href="#" uk-slidenav-next uk-slider-item="next"></a>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="uk-visible@s">
                                                    <a class="uk-position-center-left-out uk-position-small" href="#" uk-slidenav-previous uk-slider-item="previous"></a>
                                                    <a class="uk-position-center-right-out uk-position-small" href="#" uk-slidenav-next uk-slider-item="next"></a>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                            <ul class="uk-slider-nav uk-dotnav uk-flex-center uk-margin"></ul>

                                        </div>





                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <? endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        <?endif;?>

var_dump() одного элемента массива из таксономии.
в var_dump($term) выводится следующее -

object(WP_Term)[7699]
public 'term_id' => int 49
public 'name' => string '1. Dealing Desk &amp; Risk Management' 
(length=37)
public 'slug' => string '1-dealing-desk-amp-risk-management' 
(length=34)
public 'term_group' => int 0
public 'term_taxonomy_id' => int 49
public 'taxonomy' => string 'solutions_cat' (length=13)
public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
public 'parent' => int 0
public 'count' => int 4
public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
```

Comment: В чем вопрос-то? что именно "так происходит"?

Comment: не выводятся посты этой таксономии в этой функции.

Comment: $posts = get_posts($args); эта строка не может вывести посты по заданным аргументам. пробовал добавить на всякий случай таксономию явно - не помогло. http://take.ms/hVy8h